# When using searchable in grails can components be stacked?

Tags: grails, searchable

I'm trying to work on a vehicles database, and have domain classes for Manufacturer, Model, and Trim and am trying to use searchable to search across all 3.

Can I set up a chain of searchable components to achieve this?

For example in Manufacturer, configure it so that Model is a searchable component. Then in Model, configure Trim as a searchable component.

Comment: I guess the mapping `root = false` is the key to your problem. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802171/grails-searchable-plugin-query/8842209#8842209 for an example