# grails searchable plugin query

Tags: grails, groovy, lucene, searchable, compass-lucene

My Grails app is using the searchable plugin, which builds on Compass and Lucene to provide search functionality. I have two searchable classes, say Author and Book. I have mapped these classes to the search index, so that only certain fields can be searched.

To perform a search across both classes I simply call

```
def results = searchableService.search(query)
```

One of the nice features of doing the search across both class simultaneously, is that the `results` object includes metadata about number of results included, number of results available, pagination details etc.

I recently added a boolean `approved` flag to the Book class and I never want unapproved books to appear in the search results. One option is to replace the call above with:

```
def bookResults = Book.search(query + " approved:1")
def authorResults = Author.search(query)
```

However, I now need to figure out how to combine the metadata for both results, which is likely to be tricky (particularly pagination).

Is there a way to search across Book and Author with a single query, but only return approved books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a test app and came to the following solution. maybe it helps...

if the property `approved` only has the states `0` and `1`, the following query will work:

```
def results = searchableService.search(
    "(${query} AND approved:1) OR (${query} -approved:0 -approved:1)"
)
```

I guess this can be reformulated in a better way if you don't use the QueryParser but the BooleanQueryBuilder.

**BTW:** if you add a method like

```
String getType() { "Book" }
```

and

```
String getType() { "Author" }
```

To your domains, you can even configure your search to do it like this

```
def results = searchableService.search(
    "(${query} AND approved:1) OR (${query} AND type:Author)"
)
```

Comment: I admire your persistence. The solution above seems to work, thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to be able to find authors or do you want to find books with a given author?

If you want to find books with a given author, you can configure your domain classes in the following way:

```
class Author {
    String name
    ...

    static searchable = {
        root false
    }    
}
```

this will result in excluding the Author from the `searchableService.search(query)`-result and you'll find field names like `$/Book/Author/name` in your index. (use luke to examine your index: http://code.google.com/p/luke/).

You can change the name of those fields by configuring a better `prefix` in your Book-class:

```
class Book {
    String name
    Author author
    ...

    static searchable = {
        author component: [prefix: 'author']
    }    
}
```

this will change the name of the field in the index to `bookauthor`.

If you now search with `searchableService.search(query)`, you'll find all books where the name of the book or the name of the author contains the search term. You can even restrict the search to a given author by using the `authorname:xyz` syntax.

---

If you really would like to mix the search results, I only know the solution you already mentioned: mixing both results with your own code, but I guess it will be hard to mix the scoring of the hits in a good way.

Update to your response: Here's my pagination code...

.gsp:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <g:paginate total="${resultsTotal}" params="[q: params.q]"/>
</div>
```

controller:

```
result = searchableService.search(params.q, params)
[
  resultList: result.results, 
  resultsTotal: result.total
]
```

So if you just merge the results of your two searches and add the `result.total`s, this could work for you.

Comment: I want to be able to find books and authors with a single query, but never include unapproved books in the results. The problem with doing 2 queries is that it's difficult to combine the 2 sets of metadata into a single set. For example if I have 2 pages of book results and 2 pages of author results, that doesn't necessarily mean I have 4 pages of results in total

Comment: Sorry, I guess I miss something here. Isn't is the case that if you have 15 book results and 17 author results, you'll always have 32 results together -> 4 page (with 10 results each)

Comment: Yes, but if I have 11 book results (2 pages) and 11 author results (2 pages), then if I combine the results I can fit them into 3 pages.

Comment: A better example of where combining the queries is difficult is navigating to the next page of results. If I perform a single Query, the plugin will generate URLs for viewing the next/previous page of results. If I perform 2 separate queries, it will only generate URLs for viewing the next/previous page of results for each subquery.

Comment: I see. I don't use the page information from the result. I use the result size together with the default grails pagination instead.

Comment: @Don: did you solve your problem? Or is there anything left where I maybe could help?

Comment: I haven't solved my issue insofar as I still don't know how to search across multiple classes but only use the predicate `approved:1` with one of them

Comment: so a merge of the results is not a valid solution?